# Uploading a file using redux-form to node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux-form

hello i'm a using a redux-form wizzard in which i'm trying to upload an image to my nodejs server.
this is my code on submit

```
           <Form
              onSubmit={async (values) => {
                console.log(values.img);
                console.log(values.img[0]);
                console.log(values);
                setShowLoader(false);
                const [, err] = await queryServerApi(
                  "deliveryman/add",
                  values,
                  "POST",
                  false
                );
                if (err) {
                  setShowLoader(false);
                  setError({
                    visible: true,
                    message: JSON.stringify(err.errors, null, 2),
                  });
                }
              }}
            />
```

and this is the result
[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqyLo.jpg)

the problem is that the image is not uploading from the front(reactjs).. this is not a backend problem because the upload is working fine via the backend

Comment: so what's not working here?

Comment: the image is not uploading on the backend

Comment: can you edit your question at the end, it mentioned like it's working fine? "i tested my image upload on the server side via ejs and its working fine."

Comment: done.. i'm really stuck here